# Texpad lagging/running slow for no reason

Tags: performance, texpad

I'm running the newest texpad version 1.7.38 on the newest macbook pro with macOS Sierra 10.12.10. Lately it started to perform slow, it specially seems to lag (there is a delay of 0.3-0.5 s between typing and seeing the letter on the screen) when showing the symbols preview.

It also freezes for some seconds often and then goes back to normal. And it also seems to generally slow down my computer, but that might be just my impression.

Anyone experiencing similar issues? Any idea on how to solve it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe 10.12.2 (or 10.12.3beta) but certainly not 10.12.10.Please  report your problem to the developer at <[https://www.texpad.com/osx](https://www.texpad.com/osx)>?